# Customizing New Document dialog in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, templates

Just wondering whether the New Document dialog can be customized so the first screen displays the contents of the Workgroup Templates folder. At the moment you have to go New>My Templates>Workgroup Templates. For a bonus point I'd like to display extra information about the template eg where it can be used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only choice would be to use VBA, but even so things aren't that simple. There is no VBA command to open the new open document dialog like you want and no way to control what tab shows.

Instead, there is a fairly simple work around to use a VBA macro to fake the keys required to open this dialog as described in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611364/in-word-programmatically-open-new-document-dialog). You can have a fiddle to try extend it so it will automatically move to the folder you want.

Something like this:

```
SendKeys "%"
SendKeys "F"
SendKeys "N"
SendKeys "{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}"
SendKeys "{Down}{Down}"
SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

Last step is to add a button to the toolbar so when clicked it runs this macro and opens the dialog etc. Read here how to achieve this: http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tsn/tsn124.htm

Hopefully that helps. Regarding your last question, I'm afraid I don't think there's any way to display further information on the dialog.